# Is it possible to have horizontal tabs on a phone and vertical tabs on a tablet?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, android-tabhost

I'm currently designing the UI for an app that I'm creating and one thing that I thought would look nice is to use the stock ActionBar navigation tabs on phones, but then on tablets have a vertical list of the tabs appear in a pane on the left-hand side.

Is it possible to do this with just the ActionBar stuff or would I need to use a custom View? If I need to use a custom View, is there any way that I can use the same one for both phones and tablets and have it render horizontally on phones and vertically on tablets?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to do this with just the ActionBar stuff

No, sorry.

> would I need to use a custom View?

Yes.

> If I need to use a custom View, is there any way that I can use the same one for both phones and tablets and have it render horizontally on phones and vertically on tablets?

Since it would be your own custom `View`, that you would write yourself, you are welcome to make it do pretty much whatever you want.

Comment: Is there any way you would recommend having the same custom `View` handle being able to be like a tab as well as essentially like a listview?

In terms of functionality, clicking an item in the list/tabs would basically just highlight the selected item and swap out the fragment that's below/next to it so in my opinion, it makes sense that it should just be the same custom `View`. Is there maybe some way to access the `android:orientation` tag from xml and use that to specify which layout gets displayed?

Comment: @Unk: "Is there maybe some way to access the android:orientation tag from xml and use that to specify which layout gets displayed?" -- sure, the same way any other custom `View` does, via the `AttributeSet`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a diferent layout! 
layout-large for tablets
layout-small, layout-normal for cellphone!

Remember use the same ids on the elements, and this should works

Comment: But this wouldn't let me use the ActionBar's native support for navigation tabs in a vertical way would it?